# Where to locate the bibliography style file for Journal of Optimization Theory and Applications?

Tags: latex, bibtex

Where can I find the style file

```
 pmpsci_unsrt.bst
```

that is required by JOTA as per [submission guidelines](https://www.springer.com/journal/10957/submission-guidelines#Instructions%20for%20Authors_Online%20Submission) yet inexplicably is missing from the template submission ([download zip](https://static.springer.com/sgw/documents/1705114/application/zip/LaTeX%20JOTA.zip))?

Comment: A random version from the internet: https://www.cb.uu.se/~ingela/tmp/PRIP2016_Nystrom_etal/spmpsci_unsrt.bst

Comment: I bow to your search skills. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The file `spmpsci_unsrt.bst` seems indeed to be missing from the `.zip` file, but you can find it out in the wild of the internet, e.g.

[https://www.cb.uu.se/~ingela/tmp/PRIP2016_Nystrom_etal/spmpsci_unsrt.bst](https://www.cb.uu.se/%7Eingela/tmp/PRIP2016_Nystrom_etal/spmpsci_unsrt.bst)

Comment: Thanks. I'll leave it open for when they fix it.